# Schema validation in Visual Studio Code only works for the first array item at a time

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, jsonschema

I have a strange problem with the built-in JSON schema validation of MS Visual Studio Code (Ver. *1.31.1*), which I've tried to illustrate here as a *minimal*, *complete* and *verifiable* example.

So for this example, let's assume we have a file called **myjson.json**, which should be validated against a schema file **myschema.json** (full file contents are included below).

In this constellation I would expect that if you move the mouse pointer directly over an item (or item value) n VSCode's editor, the respective description text from the schema file will be displayed.

Instead, this only works for the first item in *foodItems* (Picture 1). Nothing is displayed for all other items.(Picture 2).
It looks like the further items aren't even processed by the editor at all.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a flaw in VSCode?

**Picture 1 - Mouse hover and validation working for the first item**
[image: Mouse hover and validation working for the first item]

**Picture 2 - Mouse hover and validation not working for all subsequent items**
[image: Mouse hover and validation not working for all subsequent items]

---

The file contents:

---

**myschema.json**

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "My Schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "foodItems": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": [ {"$ref": "#/definitions/foodItem"} ]
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "foodItemApple": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "const": "Apple"
                },
                "amount": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "description": "The current amount of apples"
                }
            },
            "required": ["name", "amount"],
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        "foodItemOrange": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "const": "Orange"
                },
                "amount": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "description": "The current amount of oranges"
                }
            },
            "required": ["name", "amount"
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        "foodItemCherry": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "const": "Cherry"
                },
                "amount": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "description": "The current amount of cherries"
                }
            },
            "required": ["name", "amount"],
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        "foodItem": {
            "anyOf": [
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/foodItemApple"},
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/foodItemOrange"},
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/foodItemCherry"}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

---

**myjson.json**

```json
{
    "$schema": "./myschema.json"  ,
    "foodItems": [
        {
            "name": "Apple",
            "amount": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "Orange",
            "amount": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "Cherry",
            "amount": 0        
        }
    ] 
}
```

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you made a mistake that's very easy to miss.

`items` can be an array of JSON schema objects, or a JSON Schema object.

If it's an object, then all items in the applicable array must match the subschema (which is what you want).

If it's an array, it applies the schemas in the array to the objects in the applicable array at the same index (which is what you have).

> If "items" is a schema, validation succeeds if all elements in the
> array successfully validate against that schema.
>
> If "items" is an array of schemas, validation succeeds if each
> element of the instance validates against the schema at the same
> position, if any.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.4.1

Essentially, remove the square braces around the schema from the `items` property value.

I haven't checked your schema for other issues, though.

Comment: Welcome! Feel free to come by the JSON Schema community slack if you have questions that don't fit on Stack Overflow. If you're able, please consider buying me a coffee: https://www.buymeacoffee.com/relequestual =]